# pymc3 chain reaching maximum tree depth

Tags: python, bayesian, sampling, pymc3

I am building a model for using comparisons between pairs of deals as input to estimate weights that define the value function of the ranking party. Maybe this sounds like gibberish, but my question regards the pymc3 sampler. I get this error:

> The chain reached the maximum tree depth. Increase max_treedepth, increase target_accept or reparameterize.

I am not sure what I can do about this error. For reproducability, I include my code below. Any advice would be warmly welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

true_B_batna = 20

def true_B_value(quality, delivery, price):
    return quality*30 + delivery*10 - price - true_B_batna

true_sd = 10

def noisy_B_value(quality, delivery, price):
    tv = true_B_value(quality, delivery, price)
    return np.random.normal(tv, true_sd)

quality_range = np.arange(1,11,1)
delivery_range = np.arange(1,4,1)
price_range = np.arange(0,101,10)

def generate_random_deal():
    return (np.random.choice(quality_range),
            np.random.choice(delivery_range),
            np.random.choice(price_range))

qualities, deliveries, prices, B_values = [], [], [], []

nr_deals = 5

for i in range(nr_deals):
    rnd_deal = generate_random_deal()
    qualities.append(rnd_deal[0])
    deliveries.append(rnd_deal[0])
    prices.append(rnd_deal[0])
    B_values.append(noisy_B_value(*rnd_deal))

deals = pd.DataFrame({"quality":qualities, "delivery":deliveries, "price":prices, "est_value": B_values})
deals = deals.sort_values(by = "est_value", ascending=False)
deals["rank"] = np.arange(len(deals))
deals = deals.set_index("rank")

deal_vector = deals[["quality", "delivery", "price"]].values

nr_comparisons = 8

comparisons = []
weights = []
d1, d2, weight = [], [], []
for _ in range(nr_comparisons):
    first = np.random.choice(deals.index)
    while True:
        second = np.random.choice(deals.index)
        if second != first and (first, second) not in comparisons and (second, first) not in comparisons:
            comparisons.append((first, second))
            break

    d1_val = deals.iloc[first].est_value
    d2_val = deals.iloc[second].est_value
    if d1_val - d2_val < -100:
        weight = 1
    elif d1_val - d2_val < -25:
        weight = 0.5
    elif d1_val < 25:
        weight = 0
    elif d1_val < 100:
        weight = -0.5
    else:
        weight = -1

    weights.append(weight)

comp_df = pd.DataFrame({"first": [c[0] for c in comparisons], "second": [c[1] for c in comparisons], "weight": weights})

comparison_matrix = np.array(comparisons)

weight_vector = np.array(weights).reshape(1,len(weights)).T

num_items = len(deals)
num_params = 3
FIRST = 0
LAST = 1

model = pm.Model()

with model:
    W = pm.Normal("W", mu=0, sigma=50, shape=num_params)

    BATNA = pm.Normal("BATNA", mu=0, sigma=50)

    value = pm.Deterministic("value", pm.math.sum(W*deal_vector, axis=1) - BATNA)

    err = pm.Normal("err", mu=0, sigma=50)

    percieved_value = pm.Deterministic("perc_val", value + err)

    comparison = pm.Deterministic(
        'comparison', (
            percieved_value[comparison_matrix[:, FIRST]] - percieved_value[comparison_matrix[:, LAST]]
        ) #This generator returns an ElemWise object
    )

    obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=comparison, sd=0.25, observed=weight_vector)

    prior_sample = pm.sample_prior_predictive(samples=2000)

with model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=4000, cores=6)

pm.plot_trace(trace)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess the slicing in the 'comparison' code might be problematic.   Maybe try refactoring it to be a linear algebra operation (both Aesara (PyMC v4) and the older Theano (PyMC v3) should have ops for this).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got the idea about the comparison from this blog post: https://jessicastringham.net/2018/05/27/coffee/
My lack of skills with bayesian modeling unfortunately prevent me from knowing exactly how to move to a linear algebra operation, but I will try!

Comment: I reparametrized this problem as a Bernoulli process of which deal wins in comparison with another, without the possibility of drawing or slightly preferring one over the other. Now it works like a charm.